# How do I add rulers to my xcode workspace

Tags: iphone, xcode, rulers

I'm trying to use guides on my xcode project but I don't have any rulers displayed on my storyboard workspace, is there a way to get rulers into the workspace?

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly a ruler, but holding down the option key with an object selected (and moving the mouse around) will show you the exact distances to the sides of the view.